# A tag "replace" justifica-se?

Tags: debate, tags

Estava aqui a ver uma pergunta e deparei-me com a tag [replace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replace) justifica-se termos esta tag?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu acho que se justifica porque substituição de texto é uma dúvida comum, e a adição de outra tag com a linguagem ajuda na filtragem. Talvez fique melhor se for em português e contextualizada (pra indicar que é substituição *de texto*). Algo como `substituição-texto`, por exemplo.

Comment: Mas, por outro lado, talvez uma tag mais genérica para processamento de texto seja suficiente. Já existe a tag [tag:string] que engloba um monte de perguntas sobre processamento de cadeias de texto, algumas inclusive sobre substituição de conteúdo.

Comment: `regex` se encaixa melhor

Answer (score 4):

Eu acho a tag demasiado genérica e possivel fonte de confusão.

Creio que facilmente ela se encaixará em demasiados contextos e assim deixar de ser especifica e perder utilidade que poderia ter

Answer (score 3):

Talvez uma tag mais genérica para processamento de texto seja suficiente. Já existe a tag [string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) que engloba um monte de perguntas sobre processamento de cadeias de texto, algumas inclusive sobre substituição de conteúdo.

Comment: Essa é a melhor solução, `string` serve não só para *replace* como também para várias outras operações sobre texto. Organizado e econômico.

Comment: @bfavaretto entretanto não se mudou nada.

Comment: @JorgeB. Na época eu removi todas as ocorrências, mas a tag ressurgiu. Só tem 2 perguntas hoje, a comunidade pode cuidar delas.